# snowflake: continue on error but also list all the errors

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am inserting data into snowflake using the below statement

```
    copy into "sampletable"
      from s3://test/test/ credentials=(aws_key_id='xxxx' aws_secret_key='yyyyy')
      file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|'skip_header = 1)
      on_error = 'continue';
```

but after the ingestion is done, i also want to know which rows are not inserted and whats the reason, since i am using the option `on_error = 'continue'`

any idea how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VALIDATE function: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/validate.html

Comment: can you send me the sql

Comment: i do validate `validation_mode = 'RETURN_100000_ROWS';`

but there are lot of rows.. so should i validate the whole file